# Loop through all configurations

Tags: algorithm, loops

I can't think of a good way to do this:

I want to loop through all coombinations of 6 numbers that add up to 21. The numbers have to be greater than 0 and integers.

for example:

```
 21 0 0 0 0 0 
 20 1 0 0 0 0 
 20 0 1 0 0 0 
 ...
 1 2 3 4 5 6
 etc...
```

can you guys give me a clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is similar to next_permutation problem. https://github.com/zwxxx/LeetCode/blob/master/Next_Permutation.cpp. We could solve this problem by modifying how to get the next element. Following is a sample code.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bool findNext(int *perm)
{
    if (perm[5] == 21) 
        return false;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        if (perm[i] != 0)
            break;
    perm[i+1]++;
    perm[i]--;
    if (i > 0) {
        int tmp = perm[i];
        perm[i] = perm[0];
        perm[0] = tmp;                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    }   
    return true;
}

void printPerm(int *perm)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        cout << perm[i] << " ";
    }   
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int n[6];
    n[0] = 21; 
    for (int i =1; i < 6; i++)
        n[i] = 0;
    printPerm(n);
    while (findNext(n)) {
        printPerm(n);
    }   
    printPerm(n);

}
```

Comment: Do you mean randomly pick a qualified permutation?

Comment: your sample code outputs (21,0,0,0,0,0),(0,21,0,0,0,0),(0,0,21,0,0,0),... for example. Would there be a simple way to only output one of those?

Answer (score 1):

choose a number for the first number A then find out how many combinations of 5 numbers add up to (21 - A) and so forth for all the combinations of 4 and so forth.  The 1 case can have (at most) 1 combination.  In order to maintain uniqueness you can add the constraint that the numbers have to be nonincreasing

so it'll go something like this:

```
findcombinations(sum, length, max) {

if(length == 1)
  return 1;
else {
   for(int i = 0; i <= sum && i <= max; i++)
       return findcombinations(sum - i; length -1; i)
}
}
```

Comment: +1, but the OP's example shows that he does *not* want unique sets. Also, the punctuation is wrong in your return statement (at least for any language I use on a daily basis). [Oh, and if you *are* going to generate unique sets, I'd do it in ascending order, not descending, which simplifies the `for` clause to one comparison: `for  (int i = min; i <= sum; ++i)` Just a thought.]

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Next permutation method.
Or you could use brute force with 6 nested for loops which is more simple to implement.

Here's a C# version of Next permutation converted from ChengYi He's post

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetString(this IEnumerable<int> arr)
    {
        return arr.Aggregate("", (a, b) => a + " " + b);
    }
}

class Program
{
    const int Sum = 21;
    const int Len = 6;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        Run(result);
        result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("N: {0}\nPress a key to exit", 
            result.Count));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Run(IList<string> result)
    {
        var n = new int[Len];
        n[0] = Sum;

        result.Add(n.GetString());
        while (FindNext(n))
        {
            result.Add(n.GetString());
        }
    }

    static bool FindNext(IList<int> perm)
    {
        if (perm.Last() == Sum)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < Len; i++)
        {
            if (perm[i] != 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        perm[i + 1]++;
        perm[i]--;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            int tmp = perm[i];
            perm[i] = perm[0];
            perm[0] = tmp;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The brute force version would be like this in C#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = new List<string>();
    for (int a = 0; a <= Sum; a++)
        for (int b = 0; b <= Sum; b++)
            for (int c = 0; c <= Sum; c++)
                for (int d = 0; d <= Sum; d++)
                    for (int e = 0; e <= Sum; e++)
                        for (int f = 0; f <= Sum; f++)                            
                            if(a+b+c+d+e+f==Sum)                                
                                result.Add(string.Format(
                                    "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5}",
                                        a,b,c,d,e,f));

    result.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);                            
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("N: {0}\nPress a key to exit",
                                    result.Count));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll want six nested loops (or a recursive function) and as soon as the sum hits 21 you should `break` the loop.